# Customizing Java Validation Message on Size Annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation, size

I have a simple entity class that represents a table in the DB. This class has two properties and I have a Size annotation on both of them as shown

```
public class ExecutionStepOption extends AbstractDomainObject implements Nameable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4249454967446069549L;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
@Column(name = "value")
private String value;
```

On the HTML side I have a form that has two textbox(s), which take the name and value. When the user enters a value more than 10 characters in size, I want to show a customized message like "Value is greater than 10 characters".

I tried this

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 10, message = "Size cannot be greater than 10 Characters")
@Column(name = "value")
private String value;
```

But does not seem to work. I still get the ugly Java message

```
Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
```

Stack Trace

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [org.misoenergy.darr.domain.ExecutionStepOption] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
```

List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Size cannot be greater than 10 Characters', propertyPath=value, rootBeanClass=class org.misoenergy.darr.domain.ExecutionStepOption, messageTemplate='Size cannot be greater than 10 Characters'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) ~[spring-tx-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) ~[spring-tx-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor421.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.commit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478) ~[spring-tx-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272) ~[spring-tx-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48) ~[metrics-spring-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34) ~[metrics-spring-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[metrics-spring-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.misoenergy.darr.service.ExecutionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67c89d09.saveExecutionStepOption() ~[spring-core-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.misoenergy.darr.web.rest.ExecutionResource.createExecutionStepOption(ExecutionResource.java:272) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.misoenergy.darr.web.rest.ExecutionResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$142e2153.invoke() ~[spring-core-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48) ~[metrics-spring-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34) ~[metrics-spring-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[metrics-spring-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644) ~[spring-aop-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.misoenergy.darr.web.rest.ExecutionResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a95ca53.createExecutionStepOption() ~[spring-core-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.misoenergy.darr.web.filter.gzip.GZipServletFilter.doFilter(GZipServletFilter.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:97) ~[metrics-servlet-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar:1.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:280) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar:1.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.56.jar:7.0.56]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_60]

Comment: please include the entire exception trace. Also short the imports, for Size in particular.

Comment: I just added it, it does seem like the stack trace has inside it the List of constraint violations:[
 ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Size cannot be greater than 10 Characters', propertyPath=value, rootBeanClass=class org.misoenergy.darr.domain.ExecutionStepOption, messageTemplate='Size cannot be greater than 10 Characters'}
]   Problem is how to get the message onto the HTML/AngularJS side

Comment: Is this a spring mvc app? If so show the controller class. Show the imports for your bean class so I can tell which @Size you're using.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring mvc you can keep what you're doing and add a contolleradvice something like this:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotAuthenticated(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {

        // String message =  extract violation message from exception

        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, message, 
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, request);
    }

}
```

Add logic to extract your message from the exception and change the HttpStatus to the one you like. The message will be returned in your response body.

If you can put your constraints on your DTO you can use the @Valid annotation in your controller, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stepoption", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setOption(@Valid ExecutionStepOption  stepoption) {

        return "whatever";

}
```

Which will return the custom message.

Comment: Don't you have to define this somewhere in your mvc namespace. Do I have to define <mvc:annotation-driven/> in my spring-servlet.xml?? I am working on an application using JHipster and SpringBoot using Servlet 3.0 that has no XML files but simply annotations

Comment: I had assumed (your having mention Anjular.js), that you were providing web services to your app with spring-mvc (you still have not said one way or the other). If so, you are already using the requestmapping and the Valid will also be available and will for @value annotations on the passed object. If you decide to go the other way, ControllerAdvice will be picked up if you put it in the same package as your other components or add the package to the ComponentScan annotation in your configuration java class which I assume you have from your "no XML" statement.

Comment: @user3799365, how did you resolve this? because you fixed it, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class})
    @ResponseBody 
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotAuthenticated(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new Basis(ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
```

which is pretty similar to what @BillFromHawaii is using